# Android Studio Virtual Device error starting the device

Tags: android-studio, windows-7-x64

[**Android Studio Virtual Device Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaRgs.png)

I Installed a fresh copy of windows 7 to try debug this issue.

When creating a virtual device I get an error HAXM Device Not found.

I have been investigating this error now for the last 3 days. And no solution yet. I have found multiple threads on stackoverflow for similar issues but none of them have fixed my problem.

I have installed Haxm and VT-x has been enabled in my BIOS. I even disabled it and re-enabled it.

I also installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) manually through the SDK manager to see if that would fix it. But still did not solve anything.

It is also a fresh installation of Android Studio.

I also have no 3rd party security software installed and have disabled my firewall as well. And I have also tried running the Android studio as administrator and no fix.

I also installed this security update from Microsoft because it was a solution on one of the stack overflow threads, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46148 and it did not fix the problem.

Please any help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had this issue, 
I downloaded HAXM from this site

https://www.filecroco.com/download-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/download/

And I moved the HAXM install folder from

C:\Intel

into program files folder(x86)

C:\Program Files (x86)\haxm-master

Once I had done that this issue disappeared.